# how to add days to django annotate date field from already built annotation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, python-dateutil

my model looks like this

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey()
    date = models.DateField()
    field1 = models.FloatField()
    field2 = models.FloatField()
```

I have a below queryset

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(user_id__exact=5) \
                       .annotate(weekstartdate=Trunc('date', 'week')) \
                       .values('weekstartdate') \
                       .annotate(avg_field1=Avg('field1')) \
                       .annotate(avg_field2=Avg('field2')) \
                       .order_by('-weekstartdate')
```

which is working perfectly. now I want to add  weekenddate field to above queryset which has a date = weekstartdate + 6 days. I have added below line to above query

```
.annotate(weekenddate=Trunc('date', 'week') + timedelta(days=7), output_field=DateField())
```

but it is complaining :-

> TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s):
> <django.db.models.fields.DateField>

Relative imports

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F, DateField
```

Note :-
Simple for loop after queryset is not i am looking for because after assigning manually a field, queryset filter is still fetching query from old queryset due to laziness of the queryset.
If answer can be in relativedelta of dateutil library it would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ExpressionWrapper` around it.

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(
    weekenddate=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        Trunc('date', 'week') + timedelta(days=7),
        output_field=models.DateField(),
    ),
)
```